# spotify installation error

Tags: linux, software-installation, package-management, dependencies

I have tried installing Spotify on linux but getting this error.

```
spotify-client : Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not installable
              Recommends: libavcodec57 but it is not installable or
                          libavcodec-extra57 but it is not installable or
                          libavcodec-ffmpeg56 but it is not installable or
                          libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 but it is not installable or
                          libavcodec54 but it is not installable or
                          libavcodec-extra-54 but it is not installable
              Recommends: libavformat57 but it is not installable or
                          libavformat-ffmpeg56 but it is not installable or
                          libavformat54 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What distribution of Linux are you using?

Comment: You need to provide some more information on your system, and for future questions you need to provide as much information as possible which will greatly help anyone trying to help solve your issue. Also, this post may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/186719/how-to-deal-with-not-installable-dependencies